# Prestashop 1.7 don't see my template file in module

Tags: php, templates, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have created a module named gestionfournisseur. I need to modify some part of frontend view in this module. For this, I had created two file:

1 - `gestionfournisseur/controllers/front/display.php`: this file content my controller logic and herit ModuleFrontController

```
<?php
class gestionfournisseurdisplayModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
  public function initContent()
  {
    parent::initContent();
    $this->setTemplate('display.tpl');
  }
}
```

2 - `gestionfournisseur/views/templates/front/display.tpl`: content the view I want to display.

```
Hello World!!
```

I generated the link to this page with the following instruction in my module main file:

```
$this->name = 'gestionfournisseur';
$this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->name,'display')
```

But, prestashop return me a big exception: No template found for display.tpl

If it can't help you, the content of my variable $this->context->smarty->getTemplateDir() look like this:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "/my_hosts/manishop/themes/classic/templates/"
]
```

Please can't you tell me what is the problems?

Thank's

Comment: make sure you have the right path to your template file

Comment: prestashop automaticaly find the template file. I'm not define anyone anywhere. According to the official documentation, the template files of my module need to bee in this 3 folders: `views/templates/front ; views/templates/admin ; views/templates/hook`.

Comment: why aren't you using `display()` ?

Comment: I don't use `display` since because official documentation use `setTemplate`. I'm starting on prestashop

Comment: I'm starting on prestashop. When I trying with display, I got this exception: `SmartyException in smarty_internal_template.php line 678:
Missing template name`

Comment: did you read the documentation properly display takes 2 params

Comment: I used `display(__FILE__,'display.tpl');`

Comment: see my answer below ,note form what i read in the documentation setTemplate is not a smarty function but a build in prestashop function

Answer (score 5):

You need to call setTemplate() function as shown below:

```
class SupercheckoutFcontModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

public function initContent()
{
        parent::initContent();
                $this->setTemplate('module:supercheckout/views/templates/front/order_detail.tpl');
}

}
```

The order_detail.tpl file should contain the following code:

```
{extends file=$layout}
{block name='content'}
    YOUR_HTML_CONTENT_HERE
{/block}
```

Answer (score 2):

After some times and some helps, I found the solution.

- Firstly, you need to indicate you template like @ventura show in her answer:

  `$this->setTemplate('module:supercheckout/views/templates/front/order_detail.tpl');`
- Secondly, to include you template in layout page, you need to `extend` the `page` template like this:

  ```
  {extends file='page.tpl'}

  {block name="page_content"}
    "trigger"
  {/block}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe int this way

```
  $this->setTemplate('module:supercheckout/views/templates/front/order_detail.tpl');
```

Comment: It work partially because It don't display my template layout. do you nknow why?